# Active Admin No Method error in foreign key relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, activeadmin, nomethoderror

I am making a notes app using Active Admin for the first time and I am running into an error that confuses me because the relationship exists my migrations are present as far as I can see in the schema. I have 2 models currently `Note` that `belongs_to` `Content` and `Content` `has_many` `:notes`  . I am trying to customize my show for Contents so it will display differently as seen below but I keep getting a no method error for `notes` this relationship is present and should work as it is a foreign key between both tables?

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :content
end
```

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :notes
end
```

```
ActiveAdmin.register Content do
    permit_params :name, note_ids: []

show title: 'Test' do
    h3 'You have ' + pluralize(content.notes.count, 'note') + ' referencing ' + `#{content.name}`
end
```

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_05_06_140826) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "namespace"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.bigint "resource_id"
    t.string "author_type"
    t.bigint "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  end

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "contents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "notes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.bigint "content_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["content_id"], name: "index_notes_on_content_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "notes", "contents"
end
```

[image: No Method Error]

Comment: Can you include the complete error with some stacktrace in the question?

Comment: Sure I will add a screenshot the application trace isnt long I am unsure if the full trace is what you would like

Comment: Is this happening in the user page or the content page? because in your admin page title you seem to have user in the proc

Comment: The content page is where this happens currently. The path is /admin/contents/1 if that helps.

Comment: OK, I don't understand then the proc { |user| ... } in the title, where is user coming from if it's the content page? Thats what I see in the error screen and its a bit different than the code you posted

Comment: That was just another Title implementation I was testing which works. It is only any kind of operation on Notes that causes this issue on the page. I don't see anything in activeadmin docs that shows any incorrect usage here and all models were successfully registered.

Comment: What happens if you just do h3 content.notes.count ?

Comment: Same undefined method error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232061/discussion-between-joel-blum-and-steveks17).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that content is ActiveRecord object? It looks like it is instance of ActiveSupport SafeBuffer.

Comment: Can you explain this I am not familiar with the ActiveSupport SafeBuffer

Comment: I don't know the details but SafeBuffer is used to render string as html in the application and SafeBuffer inherits from String. In your case, the `content` object should be a model/instance of class Content but the error message states "Undefined method notes for <ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer>" which shows that `content` is an object of type SafeBuffer. Can you insert a debugger here and see why is it happening? Is `content` a reserved word or is it being overwritten?